# Searching through a lists in dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where a few of the variables are lists. I'm trying to find a way to search for specific values from these lists.

The following is similar to what I'm using.

```
df <- data_frame(
        abc = letters[1:5],  
        lst = list(1:3, 2:6, 7:10, 
                   1, 1:5)
        )
```

I would ideally like to be able to something like the following;

```
df$result <- 1 %in% df$lst
```

This is returning the wrong result.

If I look at it irow by row I see

```
1 %in% df$lst
FALSE
1 %in% df$lst[[1]]
TRUE
```

So I think I need someway to recursively look into the lists in each row of the data frame. I'm not sure what the optimal way to do this is.

For clarity; 
This is two variables in a data frame that already has 50+ variables. I would prefer avoiding exploding out these variables but am open to the suggestion.

There is always only one list in each of these cells.

In the real data the only difference is that the row is made up of character values not numeric.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why would u store lists in data frame .

Comment: Not convinced neither... What do you mean by "prefer avoiding exploding out these variables"? Surely there's another way to achieve this, although Bg1850's solution works.

Comment: By explode out I mean seperate the elements of the list into seperate columns.

Comment: So using something like the spread function from tidyr to create variables indicating the presence of the possible items of the initial list. So my df defined above would end up looking more like;

lst, 001, 002, 003, ...

a, 1, 1, 1, ...

b, 0, 1, 1, ...

c, 0, 0, 0

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the work , but are u sure its the right approach to store lists in data frame .

`lapply(df$lst,function(x)(1 %in% x))`

```
> df
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

    abc       lst
  <chr>    <list>
1     a <int [3]>
2     b <int [5]>
3     c <int [4]>
4     d <dbl [1]>
5     e <int [5]>
> lapply(df$lst,function(x)(1 %in% x))
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE

[[5]]
[1] TRUE

>
```

Comment: Good solution... Also could use `sapply()`, thus having a vector as a result, rather than a list.

Comment: Thanks Bg1850! This is perfect!

I agree the df isn't great to work with. I've looked at exploding out the elements of the lists into separate variables. There are other complexities that restrict the usefulness of that. 

But were you thinking about a different option?

Comment: I will use plain list of lists ,that way u have easier time referencing elements ,also bear in mind dataframe is also a list .you should use a data frame for any dataset that fits in that 2d structure. Essentially, you use data frames  where a column refers a variable  and a row refers  a single observation of that variable(key word is  single observation) ,for anything else  lists are the way to go.